# Can't get value from input with .value

Tags: javascript

I can't figure out why .value isn't working. I've also tried .querySelector instead of .getElementById, but I keep getting undefined in the console.

```js
var submit = document.querySelector('#submit');
var name = document.getElementById('ship-name');

submit.onclick = function() {
  console.log(name.value);
};
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <h2>Where do you want your stuff sent?</h2>
  <label for="ship-name">
    <input class="full text-input" id="ship-name" type="text" placeholder="Name" required>
  </label>
  <label for="ship-add-1">
    <input class="full text-input" id="ship-add-1" type="text" placeholder="Address Line 1" required>
  </label>
  <label for="ship-add-2">
    <input class="full text-input" id="ship-add-2" type="text" placeholder="Address Line 2" required>
  </label>
  <label for="ship-add-3">
    <input class="full text-input" id="ship-add-3" type="text" placeholder="Address Line 3" required>
  </label>
  <label for="ship-4">
    <input class="full text-input" id="ship-add-4" type="text" placeholder="Address Line 4" required>
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Where's an element with the ID of `submit`?

Comment: You cannot create a variable called `name` in the global scope. This will be a reference to `window.name` which will always be a string.

Comment: When I run the snippet in SO, it throws an error saying you can't set property 'onclick' of null - maybe this has something to do with it?

Comment: *Cannot set property 'onclick' of null* is due to the fact that `submit` does not exist in the snippet. But even if it is added, `name` will be a string and not an element, and a string doesn't have a `value` property. Just rename the variable `shipName` or something else, and the problem will go away.

Comment: Thank you David, that did it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone. David H's answer fixed the issue. I just changed the variable name to something else and it worked. He was right that you can't have a variable called name in the global scope.

Answer (score 0):

change the code in your .js file to be:

```
document.getElementById('submit').onclick = function () {
 console.log(document.getElementById('ship-name').value);
}
```

as mentioned in the comments you are misusing global space.

Also, remember to include the script after the html it is referencing.

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried?

```
var name = $('#ship-name').val();
```

And then

```
console.log(name);
```

Comment: Is not about jquery.

Comment: Does your button has the id property set to "submit"?

Comment: Yeah, the button is working and the click is being recognized.